# What is the term for an area in a studio, with a backdrop, floor cover, and props?

Tags: terminology

I am in the very beginning stages of exploring my interest in becoming a photographer. My photography specific vocabulary isn’t what it should be yet, so please bear with me.

When you set up an area in a studio, with a backdrop, floor cover, and props, what is that called? A “set”? A “scene”?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a **set**.
It shares terminology with the TV/film industry.

The building is the **studio**. The definition would include pretty much any building with room[s] designed or modified to be used for photography/cinematography.
It contains one or more specific areas constructed for a particular shoot. Each of these areas - whether it's a mock-up of the entire interior of a stately home, or a simple backdrop & a small stand to rest a beer bottle - is a **set**.

This extends to even when you're not in the studio. Your chosen building or outdoor area is then your **location**. Any area within that reserved for the shoot itself is also the **set**, even if no construction was necessary except for lighting.

I think this naming convention is to save confusion for the many people who may not be in the same location two days in a row.
You start at **base** [which has parking, somewhere to relax, food, hair, costume], are transferred to **location** & when needed you go to **set**... wherever it is.

Answer (score 0):

It can be called a set, which is shared with the TV/film crowd.

I've also heard it referenced as a 'portrait setup.'

One of the latest fads at events is to call it a 'photo booth', even though there is no actual booth to sit in anywhere in sight.¹

<sub>¹ Yes, that's one of my pet peeves. You can't have a proper "photo booth" without an actual booth.</sub>